# Deleting certain words depending on length of the value

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a concatenation in a query that takes values from different fields and creates the product name. My issue here is I need to keep the name under 80 characters, so if it passes 80 characters there
are certain key words in the "name" that I should be able to delete. For example

```
Oracle Lights 79-80 American Motors AMX 4x6" LED Amber Halo 2 Sealed Headlights
```

Is fine, it's just under 80 characters.

But for:

```
Oracle Lights 79-83 American Motors Concord 4x6" LED ColorSHIFT Halo 2 Sealed Headlights
```

this is 88 characters, so I have to figure out a way that if this concatenation is too long, the word `Lights` can be deleted. And if its still over 80 characters, then the world `Oracle` should be deleted.

For anyone that wants to know the field `[year_single] = 79-80, [make] = American Motors, [model] = AMX, and [color] = Amber`. Everything else is string that is added in the concatenation because its static.

Anyone know a way I can do this ?

Comment: Since it may get complicated deciding which values to truncate and the need to truncate multiple values, I would suggest using a VBA function where you pass the original string and have it return your desired result. If you need help with the function, please provide the rules and which keywords to truncate.  Also, can you use abbreviations.. i.e. HL for headlights, etc.?

Comment: unfortunately I can't use abbreviations. and I'll edit the original post with rules and keywords

Comment: Removing just "Lights" from your sample string will leave behind 2 consecutive spaces.  Is that a concern?

Comment: It would, I'm guessing the platform we would eventually upload to would count the extra spaces as characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok thanks to Phicon for pushing me in the right direction. I created a function that takes a string and checks its length, then takes out "Lights" if the string is over 80 characters, and "Oracle" afterward if it's still over 80 characters, then called it in an update query.

```
Public Function shortname(value As String) As String
    Dim temp As String
    temp = value

    If Len(temp) > 80 Then temp = Replace(temp, "Lights ", "", 1, 1)
    If Len(temp) > 80 Then temp = Replace(temp, "Oracle ", "", 1, 1)

    shortname = temp
End Function
```

update query:

```
UPDATE tbldata SET name = shortname(name);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try the follwing in the vba.

```
if len(yourfield) > 80 then Replace(yourfield, "Lights ", "") end if
if len(yourfield) > 80 then Replace(yourfield, "Oracle ", "") end if
```

Comment: I'd add the space in there so you don't have extra characters.  Like: Replace(yourfield, "Lights_", "") but replace the underscore with a spacebar.  I had to add the underscore because it was hard to see there was a space there.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Good point. It would also avoid the problem with the original code in that `Replace(... ,"Lights","")`  would return *'Oracle  79-83 American Motors Concord 4x6" LED ColorSHIFT Halo 2 Sealed Head'* because `Replace()` is case-insensitive.

Comment: interesting!I didn't even realize that "lights" in headlights might also be taken out. I'll implement it and see what I can get.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how I would implement it into vba, i get "compile errors, expected end of statement"

Answer (score 2):

For the SQL "purists" out there, here's one way to do it without a VBA. Given an actual data table named [tblData]

```
ID  year_single  make             model    color     
--  -----------  ---------------  -------  ----------
 1  79-80        American Motors  AMX      Amber     
 2  79-83        American Motors  Concord  ColorSHIFT
```

and tables containing the possible variations on the filler text:

[tblFiller1]

```
Filler1      
-------------

Oracle       
Oracle Lights
```

[tblFiller2]

```
Filler2 
--------
4x6"    
4x6" LED
```

and [tblFiller3]

```
Filler3                 
------------------------
Halo 2 Sealed Headlights
```

we can create a saved Access query named [qryDescripOptions]

```sql
SELECT
    ID,
    Len(Descrip) AS DescripLen,
    Descrip
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            ID,
            Filler1 & IIf(Len(Nz(Filler1,""))>0," ","") & 
                year_single & " " & make & " " & model & 
                IIf(Len(Nz(Filler2,""))>0," ","") & Filler2 & 
                " " & color & 
                IIf(Len(Nz(Filler3,""))>0," ","") & Filler3
                AS Descrip
        FROM
            tblData, tblFiller1, tblFiller2, tblFiller3
    )
```

which uses cross-JOINs on the tables to give us all of the permutations:

```
ID  DescripLen  Descrip                                                                                 
--  ----------  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1          61  79-80 American Motors AMX 4x6" Amber Halo 2 Sealed Headlights                           
 2          70  79-83 American Motors Concord 4x6" ColorSHIFT Halo 2 Sealed Headlights                  
 1          65  79-80 American Motors AMX 4x6" LED Amber Halo 2 Sealed Headlights                       
 2          74  79-83 American Motors Concord 4x6" LED ColorSHIFT Halo 2 Sealed Headlights              
 1          68  Oracle 79-80 American Motors AMX 4x6" Amber Halo 2 Sealed Headlights                    
 2          77  Oracle 79-83 American Motors Concord 4x6" ColorSHIFT Halo 2 Sealed Headlights           
 1          72  Oracle 79-80 American Motors AMX 4x6" LED Amber Halo 2 Sealed Headlights                
 2          81  Oracle 79-83 American Motors Concord 4x6" LED ColorSHIFT Halo 2 Sealed Headlights       
 1          75  Oracle Lights 79-80 American Motors AMX 4x6" Amber Halo 2 Sealed Headlights             
 2          84  Oracle Lights 79-83 American Motors Concord 4x6" ColorSHIFT Halo 2 Sealed Headlights    
 1          79  Oracle Lights 79-80 American Motors AMX 4x6" LED Amber Halo 2 Sealed Headlights         
 2          88  Oracle Lights 79-83 American Motors Concord 4x6" LED ColorSHIFT Halo 2 Sealed Headlights
```

So the query

```sql
SELECT
    ID,
    MAX(DescripLen) AS MaxOfDescripLen
FROM qryDescripOptions
WHERE Descriplen<=80
GROUP BY ID
```

gives us the length of the longest description for each ID that still fits in 80 characters

```
ID  MaxOfDescripLen
--  ---------------
 1               79
 2               77
```

Now we can join that back to our saved query to retrieve the actual descriptions

```sql
SELECT
    q.ID,
    q.Descrip
FROM
    qryDescripOptions q
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            ID,
            MAX(DescripLen) AS MaxOfDescripLen
        FROM qryDescripOptions
        WHERE Descriplen<=80
        GROUP BY ID
    ) maxlen
        ON q.ID = maxlen.ID AND q.DescripLen = maxlen.MaxOfDescripLen
```

producing

```
ID  Descrip                                                                        
--  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  Oracle Lights 79-80 American Motors AMX 4x6" LED Amber Halo 2 Sealed Headlights
 2  Oracle 79-83 American Motors Concord 4x6" ColorSHIFT Halo 2 Sealed Headlights
```

In this particular case there are no duplicates caused by "ties" on the MaxOfDescripLen value for a given ID, but to prevent that possibility we would wrap the whole thing in an aggregation query

```sql
SELECT 
    ID, 
    MIN(Descrip) AS Description
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            q.ID,
            q.Descrip
        FROM
            qryDescripOptions q
            INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT
                    ID,
                    MAX(DescripLen) AS MaxOfDescripLen
                FROM qryDescripOptions
                WHERE Descriplen<=80
                GROUP BY ID
            ) maxlen
                ON q.ID = maxlen.ID AND q.DescripLen = maxlen.MaxOfDescripLen
    )
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: thank you for the input. I see so you had to create separate tables for the filler text before running the actual query, I'm creating the name in a query already, so let me tinker around and see how I could try and place this in there. I'm also trying to understand how you did this, especially wrapping it in an aggregation query.